Shielding for 5V Electromagnet - 25 kg Holding Force - P40/20
I want to use two of these electromagnets in a quick-release mechanism. The issue is that there are other hardware in general proximity of these electromagnets, such as IMUs and BLDCs. I want to shield the magnetic interference to the best without adding too many layers of shielding (max 4mm). What are the best materials to use for shielding? I saw Mu-Metal, but don't know if it is applicable to this scenario.
https://www.adafruit.com/product/3875 This is the link for the electromagnet

u-metal are used for "weak" magnetics ...

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

An IMU (unless it incorporates a compass sensor) and BLDC motors should not be affected by a nearby magnet (switching it may produce EMI though).  In any case, to determine the type and amount of shielding you need to know the nature of the unwanted fields and the susceptibility of what you are trying to protect.
